# How can I test a MessageBodyWriter for a List<Some>?

Tags: jaxb, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS resource method.

```java
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Some> list() {

    final List<Some> list = get();

    // list and each elements are ok.

    return list;
}
```

The problem is that `application/xml` generates an 500 without any specific server(tomcat) log.

`application/json` works fine.

I check JAXB-marshaller for every element in `list`.

How can I debug this? How can I test any `MessageBodyWriter` for `List<Some>`?

**UPDATE**

The root cause of this problem (500 without a error log) is a wrongly JAXB-annotated class.

I created an `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` as @peeskillet suggested.

```java
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

Then I could see what error JAXB made. I still don't understand why any JAXB-error is not reported.

Comment: _"How can I debug this?"_ - Try making an `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` and printing the stacktrace from the exception. Hard to debug without seeing the cause of the 500. I'm surprised it isn't already logged somewhere though.

Comment: @peeskillet You should write an answer not a comment so that I can accept it.

Comment: First did it work? And were you able to find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "How can I debug this?"

Sometimes when errors/exceptions aren't being logged, I'll create an

```
ExceptionMapper<Throwable or Exception>
```

and just print the stack trace. If the exception is being thrown in the JAX-RS context, it should go through the mapper.

- See [more about exception mapping](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6501)