# Dropwizard. Send Json and make jersey + jackson recognize class

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, dropwizard

i am farley new to jackson and jersey. Have done some programs that uses those libraries. But i have a problem that i cant find a solution for.

```
  @POST
  @Path("/submit")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public void submitTicket(Ticket ticket)
  {
    System.out.println("*** SUBMIT A NEW TICKET ***");
    System.out.println("Ticket: " + ticket);
  }
```

This is in my `ticketResource` class. I am trying to send json from my webapplication to the server. But i only get error's when trying.

```
    $('#newTicketSubmit').click(function () {
    var jsonData = [
       {'topic':$('#inputTopic').val()},
       {'priority':$('#inputPriority option:selected').val()},
       {'assigned':$('#inputAssign option:selected').val()},
       {'text':$('#inputText').val()},
       {'solved':0},
       {'date':'No date set'}
    ];




    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ticket/submit',
        // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data){alert(data);},
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
  });
```

This is how my javascript file looks like. It does call the server. But i am not 100% sure if i am doing everything correctly

```
public class Ticket {

  public Ticket()
  {
    /* Empty */
  }


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @JsonProperty
  private int id;

  @NotEmpty
  @JsonProperty
  private String topic;

  @NotEmpty
  @JsonProperty
  private String text;

  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty
  private int solved;

  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty
  private int priority;

  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty
  private int assigned;

  @NotEmpty
  @JsonProperty
  private String date;
```

And lastly here is a snipped of my `Ticket` class
What i want my project to understand is that when i send something from the javascript app. Then the server would understand how to create a Ticket class from that json data. If i understand everything correctly. That should be possible. But i am doing something wrong somehow.

Any help that could take me on the right path is more than welcome

```
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse: A message body writer for Java class io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.ErrorMessage, and Java type class io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.ErrorMessage, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
application/octet-stream ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
```

**Stracktrace of exception:**

javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class io.dropwizard.jersey.validation.ValidationErrorMessage, and Java type class io.dropwizard.jersey.validation.ValidationErrorMessage, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.

```
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:284)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:348)
at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipFilter.doFilter(BiDiGzipFilter.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486)
at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:519)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1097)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:448)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1031)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:173)
at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:92)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:446)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:271)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:246)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It would help to know the error, but this looks suspect `contentType: 'json'`. Should be `application/json` not just `json`. You cas use `dataType:json`, but `contentType` set the `Content-Type` header, and `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON == "application/json"`. I think jQuery will implicitly set the content type as `application/json` anyway, without having to specify the `contentType` or even the `dataType`. I may be wrong. If this change doesn't help, please post the errors/exceptions/logs

Comment: ah sorry forgot to change it back. It was set to application/json before. But it still does not work when i have it like that or even remove dataType

Comment: Don't use `void` as a return type. Try to use `Response` and return `Response.ok("Message").build()` and see what happens. Or simply try return type `String` and return `"Hello"`. Either way doesn't matter. But I think the problem is with the void return

Comment: That did not help im afraid. Same error message. The thing is. it does not get into the function. when i have the Ticket class as a parameter

Comment: Do you have getter and setters?

Comment: yes i have both getters and setters for the ticket class

Comment: Also try and set `accept:application/json` in the ajax request. You should be able to get the error message back from the ajax request. Right now the `ErrorMessage` can't be serialized. The error you are posting is not useful, because it's not giving the actual cause of the error, but just that the error message can't be serialized. We need to know the actual cause of the error

Comment: You can also use an `ExceptionMapper` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28151049/2587435) to try print out the stacktrace if it current;y not doing so

Comment: I added a exception stracktrace. But i do not know if that helped me understand the problem any further

Comment: It's a validation problem. Did you already set `accept:'application/json'` in the ajax request? You need to find out what that validation problem is. You should be able to get the returned message. I would imagine it's in json. Also try and get rid of all the validation annotations to see if it works. If it does, try and adding one by one back. Also `$().val()` returns a string. You need to `parseInt(..)` it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i found a solution for my problem yesterday. The problem was my implementation of the Json data

```
   var jsonData = {
     'topic':$('#inputTopic').val(),
     'priority':parseInt($('#inputPriority option:selected').val()),
     'assigned':parseInt($('#inputAssign option:selected').val()),
     'text':$('#inputText').val(),
     'solved':0,
     'date':'No date set'
  };
```

This is a example of a working Json data in javascript.